# Unable to run Ansible 'expect' module

Tags: ansible

I am trying to run an Ansible script that  invokes the 'expect' module (see end of the message).

When I run it, I get error:

> The pexpect python module is required

Yet, the pip task for installing pexpect runs without error.

What am I doing wrong?

Thx.

Alain Désilets

=== Playbook content ===

```
---
- name: Run Anaconda shell

  hosts: all
  vars:
      conda_home: "~/anaconda2-NEW"
      conda_inst_sh_path: /path/to/Anaconda2-2018.12-MacOSX-x86_64.sh

  tasks:

    - name: install pexpect
      pip:
        name: pexpect
      become: yes
      become_user: root

    - name: Run anaconda installation script
      expect:
        command: "sh {{conda_inst_sh_path}}"
        responses:
          (?i)password: "MySekretPa$$word"
      become: yes
      become_user: root
```

Comment: Possibly different Python installations on the remote host.

Answer (score 0):

As the Ansible documentation of the [expect module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/expect_module.html) states:

> The below requirements are needed on the host that executes this module.
>   
> `python  >= 2.6`
>   
> `pexpect >= 3.3`

You need to install `pexpect` in a minimum version of `3.3` besides `python` >= `2.6` on the **target system**, that means that you have to install `pexpect` and `python` on every system, that is defined under `hosts: all`.